# gcsfuse mount with fstab fail to apply 'exec' option

Tags: ubuntu, gcsfuse

I've mounted gcp bucket with gcsfuse by fstab file.
To ellow execution of scripts and executable from the bucket, added option of 'exec' to the options in the fstab file.
Yet, this option isn't applied.

The fstab line:

```
bucketname /mount-point gcsfuse rw,uid=1001,gid=1002,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777,exec,user,allow_other,_netdev
```

The bucket is mounted, and i can read, write and modify files within the bucket.
But when i'm trying to execute something, i get 'Permission denied'.

So, unmount the bucket and try to see what is going on with 'mount -a':

```
user@server:/$ sudo mount -a
Calling gcsfuse with arguments: -o noexec -o nodev --gid 1002 --file-mode 777 --dir-mode 777 -o allow_other -o rw -o nosuid --uid 1001 bucketname /mount-point
I0611 08:33:06.783746 2023/06/11 08:33:06.783723 Start gcsfuse/0.42.5 (Go version go1.20.3) for app "" using mount point: /mount-point
```

As you can see, although the option 'exec' in the fstab options, gcsfuse still using default option 'noexec'.
I can allow execution only by the command:

```
sudo gcsfuse -file-mode=777 -dir-mode=777 -o rw -o exec -o allow_other bucketname /mount-point
```

OfCourse, after restart the problem will return, and I'll have to unmount the bucket and use this command manually again.
I need to find the way to let the fstab line work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a GCSFuse issue. I was able to fix this by using user as the first option in the fstab entry.

```
bucketname /mount-point gcsfuse user,rw,uid=1001,gid=1002,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777,exec,allow_other,_netdev
```

This is because the user option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev unless explicitly overridden by subsequent options.

Please refer to the documentation [here][1].

Thanks,
Ashmeen

[1]: [https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#:~:text=user%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Allow%20an,dev%2Csuid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#:%7E:text=user%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Allow%20an,dev%2Csuid))

Comment: Many Thanks. you've helped me a Lote!